# Python/VS Code: How to achieve IDE highlighting & auto-completion for namespaces dynamically created using `globals()`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, highlight, completion

In Python, I am dynamically creating a namespace by modifying [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#globals).

For some background, I'm masking/filtering another file to get rid of some unwanted members and wrap foreign functions with a mutex. The masked file contains auto-generated bindings for a relatively large C library that is not thread-compatible.

However, this confuses VS code syntax highlighting and auto-completion: the wrapper file's members, which are added dynamically on import time, are not recognized, and the namespace is seen as empty.

As a workaround, I thought about filtering the original namespace in place rather than masking it, but would prefer to preserve it as-is so we can still access the unmodified namespace if desired. Also, this way the IDE's namespace info would still be incorrect: dynamic changes would not be taken into account and excluded members would still be shown.

As a last resort, supposedly I could write some code to generate a PEP 484 stub file (`.pyi`), but don't like the idea of another dynamic file that is effectively unnecessary if only the IDE were smarter.

Is there an option to make VS code agnostic of `globals()`, or any other workaround to make it recognize the dynamic members?

Comment: Another idea would be to make a `.pyi` file that is a symlink to the original.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible at present. Because VS Code's language server relies on static analysis of your code to provide syntax highlighting and auto-completion, and it cannot analyze code that is generated dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I see, but nevertheless I would need some practical workaround for now to get highlighting back.
Apart from that, I'm thinking about filing a feature request with VS Code / Pylance. Maybe they can add some directive to selectively compile a file and get its namespace using `dir()` inspection rather than static analysis? Something like `# ide: compile namespace` similar to directives of code style checkers and coverage tools.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Or is there another language server I can use? I heard somewhere the previous one did some dynamic analysis?

Comment: Perhaps you could try PyCharm? VSCode is currently only a lightweight editor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I may give it a try.